# Unregister Message in Destructor make error ({"Handle is not initialized."})

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, mvvm-light

Is there anyone who experienced the same error like me:
Situation: 
- I'm using MVVMLight v4 with my window application:
- I have a windows form : such as mainform
- In code-behind class (mainform.xaml.cs), I have a constructor & a deconstructor:

```
public mainform()
{
    Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(
        this,
        msg =>
        {
           //// Do something
        }
}

~mainform()
{
    Messenger.Default.Unregister<NotificationMessage>(this);
}
```

Those code run well, but when the form is closed, an exception will be thrown:
System.InvalidOperationException {"Handle is not initialized."}
Stacktrace:

```
   at System.WeakReference.set_Target(Object value)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.FromThread(Thread thread)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.IntDestroyWindow(HandleRef hWnd)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.DestroyWindow(Object args)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.Dispose(Boolean disposing, Boolean isHwndBeingDestroyed)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.Finalize()
```

When I remove the deconstructor, no exception is thrown. & when the exception thrown, my visual studio is also crashed -> restart.

I seek out some quite similar question, but without clear answer.
Is there any advice for me?

Thanks all!

Comment: MvvmLight implements the Dispose pattern if i remember correctly, i think  you should use that instead of the finalizer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Actually, In MVVMLight v3, I found that it define explicitly CleanUp() method to do this job. But In MVVMLight 4 beta, it seems to disappear. So, I am waiting for some new update of Mvvmlight 4 beta & see what they intend to do. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

Destructors are EVIL.

Seriously you should NOT use destructors in C# if you are not releasing some unmanaged resources (which is very very rare). The way to go in your scenario is to introduce or override `Dispose` method form `IDisposable` interface and unregister there. Note that `Dispose` method will not be automatically* called like destructor is. You need to determine the place in your code that you think your `mainform` is no longer relevant and call it there. If it is a `Window` derived class then you might try removing your handler in `OnClose` event.

On the other hand if this is really a main window that is closed and then application is closed then why bother.

*as noted by Dtex MVVMLight might just do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I seems that I must do that way. I think I will add the implementation to a CleanUp() method in locator (follow MVVMLight v3). I'll try it today. :D

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However, destructors being "evil" is not a technical argument. :-) Your answer could be improved by providing references and quotes to source.

Comment: +1 for Destructors are EVIL. I'm sure Stéphane Gourichon is correct about improving with references.  Since I come from a C++ world, simply reading Destructors are EVIL and use IDisposable instead taught me that I was applying C++ practices to C#. Once I saw the error of my ways my code worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error message and copy the error [Circled in red] you will get the offending Sub or Function and a lead to what caused the error.

If you look at my message it is in the Sub libRP_AcctNo.clsFindAcctNo.Finalize() and the offending line is System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Close. When I removed these lines from Finalize the error magically dissapears.

Comment: My Apology as I did not paste the error message in my response. Here it is:
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Handle is not initialized.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.WeakReference.set_Target(Object value)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.CloseConnection(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Close()
   at libRP_AcctNo.clsFindAcctNo.Finalize()